# PySpark Dynamic mean calculation for CV-Target-Mean-Encode

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, cross-validation

Using - Python 3.6, Spark 2.3

Original DF -

```
key     a_fold_0    b_fold_0    a_fold_1    b_fold_1    a_fold_2    b_fold_2
1   1   2   3   4   5   6
2   7   5   3   5   2   1
```

I want to calculate means from the below  dataframe as follows (like this for all columns and all folds) -

```
key     a_fold_0    b_fold_0    a_fold_1    b_fold_1    a_fold_2    b_fold_2    a_fold_0_mean   b_fold_0_mean   a_fold_1_mean
1   1   2   3   4   5   6   3 + 5 / 2   4 + 6 / 2   1 + 5 / 2
2   7   5   3   5   2   1   3 + 2 / 2   5 + 1 / 2   7 + 2 / 2
```

Process -

For fold_0 my mean should be fold_1 + fold_2 / 2

For fold_1 my mean should be fold_0 + fold_2 / 2

For fold_2 my mean should be fold_0 + fold_1 / 2

For each column.

And my number of columns, no. of folds, everything would be dynamic.

How to go about this problem on a pyspark dataframe?

Trying this for creating new feature by Cross-Validation-Target-Mean-Encode technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself.

In-case anyone needs to reuse the code -

```
orig_list = ['Married-spouse-absent', 'Married-AF-spouse', 'Separated', 'Married-civ-spouse', 'Widowed', 'Divorced', 'Never-married']
k_folds = 3

cols = df.columns  # ['fnlwgt_bucketed', 'Married-spouse-absent_fold_0', 'Married-AF-spouse_fold_0', 'Separated_fold_0', 'Married-civ-spouse_fold_0', 'Widowed_fold_0', 'Divorced_fold_0', 'Never-married_fold_0', 'Married-spouse-absent_fold_1', 'Married-AF-spouse_fold_1', 'Separated_fold_1', 'Married-civ-spouse_fold_1', 'Widowed_fold_1', 'Divorced_fold_1', 'Never-married_fold_1', 'Married-spouse-absent_fold_2', 'Married-AF-spouse_fold_2', 'Separated_fold_2', 'Married-civ-spouse_fold_2', 'Widowed_fold_2', 'Divorced_fold_2', 'Never-married_fold_2']

for folds in range(k_folds):
    for column in orig_list:
        col_namer = []
        for fold in range(k_folds):
            if fold != folds:
                col_namer.append(column+'_fold_'+str(fold))
        df = df.withColumn(column+'_fold_'+str(folds)+'_mean', (sum(df[col] for col in col_namer)/(k_folds-1)))
        print(col_namer)
df.show(1)
```